# How disable two menu options from dropdown menu with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Hello colleagues I have a question, I have a site with a drop-down menu, the problem is when I hover in the menu options repeatedly there is a time when the 2 consecutive menus are open (a display: block with jQuery is applied) how can I do so that if the display: block is applied to more than one menu or more than one menu is opened, this error does not happen. I appreciate your support.

[image: Two options open]

Comment: Could you share the code that currently controls the dropdowns?

Comment: Please provide a  [mcve] that reproduces the problem

Comment: Hi @BrianH. this menu its created with megamenu plugin for wordpress, but i personalized it, you can view the menu working in this url: [link](https://trucks.staging.wpengine.com) i use this code $('#mega-menu-main #mega-menu-item-10365 .mega-menu-link').on('mouseenter',function(){ $('.menu-item').on('mouseenter',function(){
    var count = 0;
    console.log('into menu item');
  
   }); 
     
 }); for check hover.

Comment: Hi @charlietfl i have staging site here [link](https://trucks.staging.wpengine.com) and the class for menu items it´s .menu-item.

Comment: What  steps reproduce the issue? Seems to work fine for me in firefox

Comment: You can view where add the display:block in this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/jnoap6

Comment: Hi @charlietfl the error happens when you move the mouse pointer quickly and repeatedly with two menu options together.

Comment: I can't reproduce going as fast as i can back and forth on main horizontal menu. Sure I see the previous but it slides up failry quickly and never "locks in place"

Comment: @charlietfl you can see this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3RZ2kJRBPg) please.

Comment: finally got it to happen. I didn't dig into the code . If the animations are done using jQuery as in `slideUp()/slideDown()` can use `stop(true,true)` to prevent such issues http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: @charlietfl the stop() don´t work because the plugin using .css('display','block');  =(

Comment: How are animations done then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve it in case this code is useful to someone:

```
$("#news-menu").removeClass("hide");
        jQuery("ul.menu li:has(ul)").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find("ul").slideDown("fast");
    },function(){
        jQuery(this).find("ul").slideUp("fast");
    })
```

Thanks to everyone who supported me.